# Search Last 7 days excluding today Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below code to which I want to return the last 7 days excluding today (for example from 5th May - 11th May as opposed to 5th May - 12th May)

What else would I be able to include to acheive this?

```
    SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE DATE_TIME >= SYSDATE -7
```

Comment: Note that SYSDATE has a time-of-day component, which is not 00:00:00 unless you run the query at midnight. You almost surely want TRUNC(SYSDATE) for all your computations - comparing to "today" at time 00:00:00, not "today" at whatever time-of-day you happen to run the query - right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a range that starts from 7 days before midnight today and ends before midnight today:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_time >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 7
AND    date_time <  TRUNC(sysdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE DATE_TIME >= SYSDATE -7
  AND TRUNC(DATE_TIME) != TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

The `TRUNC` is needed to strip the time portion of the date column and sysdate.

Note that  `DATE_TIME >= SYSDATE -7` will include the time portion of SYSDATE and substract 7 days. If you run the query at 10AM, do you want to include rows that have date_time = sysdate - 7 at 9AM too ? If so it is better to add a `TRUNC` there too `DATE_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) -7`.

Comment: This is wrong as it will also get results from tomorrow or next year.

Comment: This almost works as it takes me right up to about 23:53 on the 11th May, however for the 5th May, it only returns data from 14:47 (when I ran the code) therefore missing data from 00:00 - 14:46 on the 5th May.
Would need a slight modification on your code.

Comment: Comparing to SYSDATE - 7, as the OP was doing, is very likely wrong to begin with.

Comment: @Sc0719 updated the answer. Change the where clause to ```DATE_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) -7``` instead